# protobuf-net merge stackoverflowexception

Tags: protobuf-net

For about 2 weeks I've been having a strange problem I really can't wrap my head around.

A quick background:
On my server app, I create a series of objects (each object with 32 bit length prefixes) and every so often I send a bunch of objects to the client. This is handled by lidgren which is pretty reliable and I don't think it's the cause of my problems.

On my client, I do this (also, it's worth mentioning that Object.Base is inherited by tons of objects):

```
public void ReadEntities(NetIncomingMessage Message)
{
     int Count = Message.ReadInt32();
     for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
     {
          ReadObject(Message);
     }
}

public void ReadObject(NetIncomingMessage Message)
{
     int Length = Message.ReadInt32();
     Deserialize(Message.ReadBytes(Length));
}

public Object.Base Deserialize(byte[] Bytes)
{
        MemoryStream SerializeStream = new MemoryStream(Bytes);
        Object.Base NewObject = Serializer.Deserialize<Object.Base>(SerializeStream);
        Object.Base ObjectExist = null;
        ObjectExist = Scene.GetEntity(NewObject.ID);

        if (ObjectExist == null)
        {
            NewObject.Initialize();
            return NewObject;
        }
        else
        {
            SerializeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Serializer.Merge<Object.Base>(SerializeStream, ObjectExist);
            return ObjectExist;
        }
}
```

It works perfectly... usually. Several updates happen where objects are deserialized and merged properly. After a few seconds though, an error pops up saying there was a StackOverflowException in protobuf-net or mscorlib. **This error goes away when I comment out the Serializer.Merge line.** Naturally, I pretty much need to use Merge for this update design to work. Furthermore, it's clearly able to deserialize since I only comment out the merge line; it's Merge which is being problematic. Really at my wits' end for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooh, that is...odd; I don't do anything non-deterministic in there (I'm the author, btw). I don't think I've got enough there for a repro (in particular, I don't know your type-model nor your specific data).

I'm more than happy to help, but I might need a bit more to reproduce that. In Visual Studio, you can *generally* capture part of a blown stack in the "Call Stack" window, which should give some indication of there the problem is. Alternatively, if you are able to post more specific information (so that I can reproduce it), either here or directly, we'll get to the bottom of it.

I'm going to make the assumption that you are using r282 (the current downloadable dll); you could *also* try using the alpha build of v2; since I don't know what the problem is (yet) I can't state that this will fix it, but if it *does* work reliably it will point at a bug in v1 (r282).

Another possibility is that there is something in your type model that is tying it in knots; perhaps some atypical getter/setter that is causing problems.

Comment: With your advice to bring up the call stack information I found the problem (the first few times I tried it it was completely unintelligible but eventually I narrowed it down, and am a bit embarrassed to not have used it earlier)! One of my ProtoMembers deep within a list of inherited objects was pointing to another object which just became really complicated. I'm not sure exactly why it would be recursive or why only merge caused problems... but it was a poor design on my part nonetheless and if I find a possible culprit I'll post it for you. Protobuf-net is hugely useful, thank you so much!